# Migrating from log4j1 to log4j2 using .properties configuration file

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

How can we add following fields in .properties configuration file for log4j2?

> log4j.appender.maa.MaxFileSize=50MB
>   log4j.appender.maa.MaxBackupIndex=100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer the **Configuration with Properties** section of [configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) on Apache website.

```
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 50MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 100
```